# Exclude index /element from for-loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have this code

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var b = ['a', 'd', 'b', 'c'];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
if (a[i] === b[i]) {
alert('ok');
  }
}
```

How could I skip in array `b` the `'d'` element, so it alerts me always Ok?

UPDATED

I just want to know how skip certain index. I mean if I don't want to look at index `0` I write for `(var i = 1; i < a.length; i ++)`, if I don't want to check last index, I do `a.length-1`, but how I skip index, if it is not first/last?

Comment: Is the (real) question: How to check if all elements of array `a` can be found in array `b`?

Comment: ^^ Or, how to check that all elements in `a` are also in `b` *in the same order*?

Comment: ^^ Or, how to check that `a` and `b` have the same contents ignoring `'d'` entries? Or...or...or...

Comment: Please could you a little more clarification as to what you want?

Comment: @evolutionxbox  I just want to know how to skip certain index (if i see index number 1 -> go to next index ( number 2). So it's more about skipping the index, not about comparing elements

Comment: @Andreas I just want to know how skip certain index. I mean if I don't want to look at index `0` I write `for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i ++)`, if I don't want to check last index, I do `a.length-1`, but how I skip index, if it is not first/last?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder as I wrote above here in the comments, I just want to skip certain index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your clarifying comment:

> I just want to know how skip certain index. I mean if I don't want to look at index 0 I write `for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i ++)`, if I don't want to check last index, I do `a.length-1`, but how I skip index, if it is not first/last?

It's more work than either of those: You need to check whether `i` is `>=` the index you want to skip when using it on `b`:

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var b = ['a', 'd', 'b', 'c'];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i ++) {
    if (a[i] === b[i >= 2 ? i + 1 : i]) {
        alert('ok');
    }
}
```

The key there is `b[i >= 2 ? i + 1 : i]`, which says "If `i` is at 2 or higher, use `i + 1`; otherwise, use `i`.

Of course, that assumes that `b` is one longer than `a`; if it isn't, at the end `b[i >= 2 ? i + 1 : i]` will result in `undefined`.

Alternately, use two loops. Or two indexes as [Jonas w suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44735915/157247).

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need

Answer (score 0):

You would need two indices:

```
var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var b = ['a', 'd', 'b', 'c'];

for (var i = 0,j=0; (i < a.length) && (j<b.length); i ++,j++) {
  if(b[j]==="d"){
    j++;//skip
  }
  if (a[i] === b[j]) {
    alert('ok');
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4wjkdgdd/

Comment: I would like to skip certain index, because there could be situation, when I don't know, what is on index 1, but  I don't want check index 1 anyway

Comment: @anna f this does the same as tj crowders...